# About tastypie and mapping multiple model classes in one single RESTful resource

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I'm doing the backend of a web application using django+tastypie+postgreSQL. And then, on another "project", my friend is implementing a frontend whitch will make use of my backend API to create AJAX calls and thus, populate the html with some data. OK. Up to this point I understand how to do it.

The problem comes when creating the different resources for my Restful API. I have, a piece of my model defined like this:

```
# COUNTRY + MANAGER
class CountryManager(models.Manager):
    def create(**kwargs):
        try:
            country = Country.objects.get(short_name=kwargs['short_name'])            
        except:
            country = Country(name=kwargs['name'], short_name=kwargs['short_name'])
            country.save()
        return country

class Country(models.Model):
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=max_short_len, unique=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=max_short_len, unique=False)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=9, default=0.0)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=9, default=0.0)
    objects = CountryManager()

# REGION +`MANAGER
class RegionManager(models.Manager):
    def create(**kwargs):
        try:
            region = Region.objects.get(short_name=kwargs['short_name'])            
        except:
            region = Region(name=kwargs['name'], short_name=kwargs['short_name'], country=kwargs['country'])
            region.save()
        return region

class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=max_short_len, unique=False, default='NoName')
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=max_short_len, unique=False, default='NoName')  
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=9, default=0.0)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=9, default=0.0)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    objects = RegionManager()

# CITY + MANAGER
class CityManager(models.Manager):
    def create(**kwargs):
        try:
            city = City.objects.get(short_name=kwargs['short_name'])
            city.lat = kwargs['lat']
            city.lon = kwargs['lon']            
        except:
            city = City(name=kwargs['name'], short_name=kwargs['short_name'], lat=kwargs['lat'], lon=kwargs['lon'])
        city.save()
        return city
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=max_short_len, unique=False)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=max_short_len, unique=False, default='NoName')
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=9, default=0.0)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=9, default=0.0)
    region = models.ForeignKey('Region')
    objects = CityManager()
```

Now, I wanted, if possible, to map my /location resource to be a mix of City, Region and Country. So if I GET /api/location/1, for example,  I would obtain a JSON with something like:

```
{"location":[
    {"city":"London", 
        "region":"London", 
        "country":"UK"
    }]
}
```

Also, if I POST /api/location/1, providing a JSON I would like to call a method placed in the City class in my models file:

```
def saveLocation(**kwargs):
    # countryN, countrySN, regionN='No region', regionSN='No region', cityN, citySN, cityLat, cityLon, locationType
        # define args
        countryN = kwargs.get('countryN', None)
        countrySN = kwargs.get('countrySN', None)
        regionN = kwargs.get('regionN', None)
        regionSN = kwargs.get('regionSN', None)
        cityN = kwargs.get('cityN', None)
        citySN = kwargs.get('citySN', None)
        cityLat = kwargs.get('cityLat', None)
        cityLon = kwargs.get('cityLon', None)
        locationType = kwargs.get('locationType', None)
        # put nulls in the args
        if regionN is None: regionN = 'No region'
        if regionSN is None: regionSN = 'No region'
        # control over the params
        if regionSN is None or countrySN is None or citySN is None: raise Exception('Invalid parameters')
        #Save the country    
        country = Country.objects.create(name=countryN, short_name=countrSN)
        countryId = country.pk
        #Save the region, if any. Else save it like "no region"
        region = Region.objects.create(name=regionN, short_name=regionSN, country = country)
        regionId = region.pk
        #Save the city
        city = City.objects.create(name=cityN, short_name=citysN, lat=cityLat, lon=cityLon, region=regionId)
        return city
```

I followed the Tastypie manual (http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html) but it only works with resource=model environments.

Also, I tryed to implement my own class MyResource(Resource) to avoid the direct model mapping that ModelsResource does. But I had no skill or knowledge to do so.

I would like to request some git repo, or some example code where I could learn how to implement a Restful API with Django without having the resource=model thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to create a Location model, or use City model as a base. Think about it, the "real" location is the city, the region and country are inherited.

My recomendation for this, is to create a simple resource (not a model resource) and implement the methods you need:

- `obj_create` for the POST part (creation): https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1018
- `obj_get_list` for GETting the list of locations (GET /location/): https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L967
- `obj_get` for GETting a single location (/location/1/): https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L992

That should cover all you need. Take a look at `ModelResource` to see how those methods are implemented.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll keep you informed!